How to create a carousel of text pages?
Using Angular js I want to create a carousel of texts and picture like this:
   Name: Jimmy          Age: 25
   Hobby: Swimming      Height: 175cm
   etc...               etc....
   Photo:                               
   Here is the photo of Jimmy

And arrow icon on the side. When you click the "<", the page goes previous, and click ">" page goes next
I looked up online and only found pictures carousel.
They just put picture urls as an array
I just wonder if there are any tools for text and picture swiper/slider?

A carousel are only a serie of "divs" that only show one at time. Inside the div you can add whatever you want. Just use an array of object and binding the properties of the variables. BTW, are you asking about AngularJs or Angular? (rememeber that AngularJS is too old)
